# python lambda - number of arguments mismatch

Tags: python, optimization, lambda, scipy

I am trying to minimize my objective function using Scipy's L-BFGS utility. I am passing my objective function and its gradient to L-BFGS as lambda expressions. I am passing exactly 6 arguments like it expects. I am unable to figure out what is wrong. I get the following error:

```
TypeError: <lambda>() takes exactly 6 arguments (5 given)
```

Here is a snippet of my code, the specific line that throws the error:

```
scipy.optimize.fmin_l_bfgs_b(func=lambda w_E,w_S,X_E,Y_E,U_E,U_S: self.ExpectationReg_ObjectiveFunction(w_E,w_S,X_E,Y_E,U_E,U_S), x0=self.w_E, fprime = lambda w_E,w_S,X_E,Y_E,U_E,U_S: self.ExpectationReg_Gradient_event(w_E,w_S,X_E,Y_E,U_E,U_S), args = (self.X_E, self.Y_E, self.U_E, self.U_S))
```

self.ExpectationReg_ObjectiveFunction and ExpectationReg_Gradient_event are functions defined in classes that this class inherits.

Just to give an idea how ExpectationReg_ObjectiveFunction looks:

```
def ExpectationReg_ObjectiveFunction(self,w_E,w_S,X_E,Y_E,U_E,U_S):
    return self.XR_OBJ(w_E,X_E,Y_E,U_E) + self.xr * self.KL_TERM(w_S,U_S) + self.l2 * np.dot(w_S.T, w_S)
```

EDIT 1: Here is the full stack trace-

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "LR.py", line 216, in <module>
lr.Train()
File "LR.py", line 159, in Train
(self.wStar_E, self.nll, self.status) = scipy.optimize.fmin_l_bfgs_b(func=lambda w_E,w_S,X_E,Y_E,U_E,U_S: self.ExpectationReg_ObjectiveFunction(w_E,w_S,X_E,Y_E,U_E,U_S), x0=self.w0_E, fprime = lambda w_E,w_S,X_E,Y_E,U_E,U_S: self.ExpectationReg_Gradient_event(w_E,w_S,X_E,Y_E,U_E,U_S), args = (self.X_E, self.Y_E, self.U_E, self.U_S),maxiter=5)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scipy/optimize/lbfgsb.py", line 185, in fmin_l_bfgs_b
**opts)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scipy/optimize/lbfgsb.py", line 314, in _minimize_lbfgsb
f, g = func_and_grad(x)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scipy/optimize/lbfgsb.py", line 263, in func_and_grad
f = fun(x, *args)
TypeError: <lambda>() takes exactly 6 arguments (5 given)
```

EDIT 2: When I put all the arguments in args-

```
scipy.optimize.fmin_l_bfgs_b(func=lambda wStar_E,w_S,X_E,Y_E,U_E,U_S: self.ExpectationReg_ObjectiveFunction(w_E,w_S,X_E,Y_E,U_E,U_S), x0=self.wStar_E, fprime = lambda w_E,w_S,X_E,Y_E,U_E,U_S: self.ExpectationReg_Gradient_event(w_E,w_S,X_E,Y_E,U_E,U_S), args = (self.X_E, self.Y_E, self.U_E, self.U_S, self.w_E,self.w_S))
```

I get the following error:

```
TypeError: <lambda>() takes exactly 6 arguments (7 given)
```

EDIT 3:

```
w_E = classifier weights for Event
w_S = classifier weights for Sentiment
X_E = Feature vector for training set of Event
Y_E = Labels Vector for event
U_E = Feature vector for unlabeled set of Event
U_S = Feature vector for unlabeled set of Sentiment
```

I am trying to minimize the objective function with respect to  `w_E` .

Comment: A very elegant one-liner :). You may want to add the full stack trace and create a somewhat reproducible example for us. Your code as it is is rather hard to debug.

Comment: Perhaps your code would be easier to debug if you changed the lambda to an actual function, even if its only temporarily. As it is its all a bit squashed in and hard to comprehend. Ever thought of giving the arguments more meaningful names aswell?

Comment: Actually the variables are quite meaningful to me, because I put them directly into code after solving the objective function. But I understand it is overwhelming for anybody else. w is weight vector. X is the feature vector, Y is the label vector. Pretty standard stuff. E stands for event, S for sentiment- the two things I want to jointly model.

Comment: I will try to make it more readable. Thanks for pointing out :)

Comment: I really recommend you to convert your code to proper function(s). Long and clever one-liners usually lead straight to the debugging hell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the issue myself. I probably had not made the situation clear enough through my question. It was complicated and confused all and sundry.

`fmin_l_bfgs_b`  takes as arguments func, fprime, x0 and args. func is the objective function to be minimized,fprime is the gradient of the objective function,x0 is the initial weight vector and args is the list of arguments.

Essentially,

`func(x,*args)`

So,  `args`  is the list of arguments other than the weight vector (with respect to which the objective function is to be minimized).

In my problem, there are two weight vectors and I minimized the objective function with respect to one of them, at a time. So `args` in my case, should contain the other weight vector too (which is NOT the one with respect to which I am minimizing the objective function). I had erroneously removed it from  `args` .

Current working code looks like the following:

```
scipy.optimize.fmin_l_bfgs_b(func=ExpectationReg_ObjectiveFunction,x0=w_E, fprime = ExpectationReg_Gradient_event, args=(w_S,X_E,Y_E,U_E,U_S))
```

Answer (score 0):

From the docs for `fmin_l_bfgs_b` (you can get this from an IPython console with `fmin_l_bfgs_b?`):

```
Parameters
----------
func : callable f(x,*args)
    Function to minimise.

...

Returns
-------
x : array_like
    Estimated position of the minimum.
```

So it looks like the signature of the `func` needs to have a single array as its first entry, which tells `scipy` what it's trying to optimise. In your case it looks like your trying to optimize both `w_E,w_S`, so you're going to have to consider them them together as a single weight vector, which you pass to your `func`:

```
w := [w_E1,...,w_Em,w_S1...,w_Sn]
```

Comment: Thanks. Though this did not solve my problem, it gave me the perspective needed to solve it.